# How to include HTML in JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I've searched for this question, there are some answers, but not exactly as my question. So, here is my jsp code:

```
<body>
    <%
        if (manager.isValid(request.getParameter("username"),request.getParameter("password"))){
            out.print("<h1> Welcome ");
            out.print(request.getParameter("username") + "</h1>");
        } else {
            out.print("<h1> Please Try Again </h1> <br />");
            out.print("Either your username or password is incorrect. Please Try again <br /> <br />");
                        }
    %>
    <%@ include file="LoginForm.html" %>
```

but instead of this, I want to include "loginForm.html" only in "else" block.
How can I do it?
Of course this doesn't work, but you'll guess what I want:

```
<%
        if (manager.isValid(request.getParameter("username"),request.getParameter("password"))){
            out.print("<h1> Welcome ");
            out.print(request.getParameter("username") + "</h1>");
        } else {
            out.print("<h1> Please Try Again </h1> <br />");
            out.print("Either your username or password is incorrect. Please Try again <br /> <br />");
            include file="LoginForm.html" ;
        }
    %>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would like to show you a way, try like below. You can try with else instead with `if`.

```
<body>
        <%
            int x = 10;
            if(x>10) {
        %>
        <%@include  file="some.html" %>
        <%
            }
        %>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also include reusable html in a jsp file function and call it for printing where needed. e.g.
config.jsp contains

```
<%!
  public void printMenu()
  {
   %>
   HTML HERE
   <%!
  }
%>
```

home.jsp contains

```
<%@include file="config.jsp"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
      <% printMenu(); %>
    <div id="PeopleTableContainer" style="width: 800px;"></div>
```

Comment: just FYI for the programmers of the future, I tried using this method and what it does is the first line <%@include file="config.jsp"%> will literally insert whatever is replaced by "HTML HERE". then when <% printMenu(); %> comes around, it will call the function like normal. So additional behavior is needed here, at least in my experience.