# How to include HTML files in JSP dynamically?

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to include dynamic HTML files in my JSP. My current code to include JSP files is as following:

```
    <jsp:include page="${file.name}.jsp" />
```

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376227/how-to-include-html-in-jsp) as well but the solution does not work for me.

My html files are in resources folder that is accessible by the application.

I used following code as well but it shows HTML code not the actual page, output is similar to following that the HTML tags are not parsed.

```
<h1>This is title of the HTML page</p><p>This is body of HTML page</p>
```

**Code**

```
    <c:import var="data" url="${url}/resources/files/${file.name}.html" />
    <c:out value="${data}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. `<c:out>` is encoding the html tags. You can use the `escapeXml` attribute to modify that behavior. See [the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) for a little more detail. To get your code working, change:

```
<c:out value="${data}" />
```

to:

```
<c:out value="${data}" escapeXml="false" />
```

Note: Be extra careful that the html you're including comes from a trusted source and/or is sanitized. Otherwise you run the risk of introducing an [XSS vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) into your application.

Comment: thanks, how about JSP? should I care about XSS if I use <jsp:include> ?

Comment: @Jack: I don't understand what you mean by "how about JSP?". And you should always care about [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) if you're including pre-built html within a web page. That includes `<jsp:include>`.

Comment: I am going to include html and jsp files that are on my own server.

Comment: @Jack How do those that html and jsp files get to your server? Do you author them yourself? Do users upload them? Do you download them from somewhere on the internet?

Comment: I have a template JSP file and those html jsp files will be imported into that template. I create and upload them all to my server.

Comment: @Jack Ok, you're probably safe in that case.